# Can you say "raise an animal"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, collocation

It was said as a way to comfort someone who had just broken up with her boyfriend, and someone said something like "go raise a dog".

I know it's okay to say *raise* an animal; I just feel so weird about it. Don't we normally say *raise* a child? I mean, in my opinion, isn't *raise* only used for human beings?

For animals, like pets, which verb is more appropriate to use? Do we just use *raise* all the time, no matter if referring to people or animals?

Comment: Daisy, welcome to this site. Could you check your question for common typing mistakes? I see many. And please check your use of commas, periods (where are they?), etc. For one thing, a space should be added after each comma.

Comment: Okay, I'll pay more attention to that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While *raise* is used for animals, it is usually in an agricultural setting. You are right to think it sounds unusual to speak of *raising* a household pet such as a dog or cat. It is much more common for someone to say that they *have* or that they *own* a dog. If one *raises* an animal, or animals, it is almost always for a specific purpose (other than companionship) such as meat production or breeding.

What this says about our use of *raise* for children, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: We raise them to serve man.

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense if you are a dog breeder, not a pet owner?

Comment: I'd expect someone to say "go _get_ a dog" or "go _adopt_ a dog". I don't know how widely spread "adopt" is for this, but I hear it a lot in the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

The New Oxford American Dictionary (in OS X) says of **raise**:

> bring up (a child) : he was born and
> raised in San Francisco.
>
> breed or
> grow (animals or plants) : they raised
> pigs and kept a pony.

The word **rear** might seem less weird to you:

> (usu. be reared) bring up
> and care for (a child) until they are
> fully grown, esp. in a particular
> manner or place : he was born and
> reared in New York City | a generation
> reared on video.
>
> breed and raise (animals) :
> the calves are reared for beef.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for animals, and plants.

> They raised pigs and kept a pony.

When referring to an animal, or a plant, *raise* means "breed or grow."

Answer (score 1):

I was taught that you raise a pig and you rear a child in English class, but no one cares or knows the difference today…just use raised for either one.

Comment: I was taught the same: that only (non-human) animals are *raised*, while children are *reared*. Alas, I venture that ***rearing children*** may not be so popular a phrase given all the paedophile-priest scandals of late.  Only dead humans like Lazarus can be *raised*; living ones only *reared*.  Words of yesteryear.

Comment: Oh no. I was raised in West Virginia.